# How could I filter product by price in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, e-commerce, mern

I'm working on a MERN stack project where users can filter products by price. Products are coming from a database and each has a price. How could I do this with react? I've no idea about how to get started working on this feature, so no code snipper is attached.

Comment: Your question is too general for us to really answer. But in broad strokes, you either do the filtering server side (by crafting your database query so that it only returns the results you care about), or you do it client side (by getting more data than you need, and then using the using things like the `.filter` method on arrays to remove results you don't care about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to filter this in the backend because this could be expensive in terms of computing resources and time (they could be thousands of product records).

So, when the user fires an event to filter by price, then a API request should be sent to your backend to filter the products in the the MongoDB collection and returns only the products the client needs.